# GRCP intercept client-side

Tags: c#, grpc, protobuf-net

I'm using protobuf-net (v1.0.123 on top of Grpc.Core, v2.30.0) and creating a proxy using

```
     var channel = new Channel(uri.Host, uri.Port, ChannelCredentials.Insecure, new []
     {
        new ChannelOption("grpc.keepalive_time_ms", oneDayMs),
        new ChannelOption("grpc.keepalive_timeout_ms", oneDayMs), 
        new ChannelOption("grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls", 1), 
     });
     var proxy = channel.CreateGrpcService<T>();
```

This works great, but after some time of inactivity, the proxy stops working and I get  `Status(StatusCode="Unknown", Detail="Stream removed", Debu...`, which I think is a keepalive problem.

My first question is: Are these options supposed to somehow be set on the server side?

It seems impossible because they're ChannelOptions, but I ask because my second question is: Is there a way to intercept client side calls? If there is, I can check for an exception when attempting and re-create the proxy (which would work for our use case). But, as best as I can tell, `Interceptor` class is strictly a server-side thing.

Basically, I'm just looking to extend the lifetime of the GRPC service, but would take any way to get there.

Comment: Keep alive on server side when enabled automatically will disconnect when channel is idle after a period of time.  The client must enable keep alive to send a message with zero length periodically so serve does not close the connection.  The server will ignore the zero length message (except to prevent the connection from closing).

Comment: @jdweng I'm not sure I'm following: How does keep alive get turned on/off server-side? How does it get enabled client-side, obviously what I'm doing isn't working.

Comment: On server there is a timer and every time a message is received the timer is reset.  When time expires the connection is closed.  On client see : https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/770

Comment: Does https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/keepalive.md answer your question: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/keepalive.md? Also note that in Grpc.Core, you CAN actually set the "ChannelOptions" when creating a server (see "new Server(channelOptions)"). Also, you can intercept calls both on server side and on the client side.